# R Markdown 2 columns should have the same names

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a table, where I've performed two statistical tests. So I've received the statistic and the p.value two times. R added after the first case a ".x" and after the second case a ".y" because it isn't possible that two colums have the same names in R.

Now I want to insert my dataframe in R Markdown and convert it to a pdf file. Is there a way to reshape the table so that the names of both columns are the same?

Here is my current table:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  statistic.x p.value.x statistic.y p.value.y
        <dbl> <chr>           <dbl> <chr>    
1       0.533 0.595          115806 0.791    
2       0.276 0.783           60380 0.674    
3      -0.481 0.633           28392 0.116    
4       2.68  0.008 * *       94507 0.195    
5       1.95  0.054           56902 0.349
```

And I want to have this table in R Markdown:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  statistic   p.value   statistic   p.value
        <dbl> <chr>           <dbl> <chr>    
1       0.533 0.595          115806 0.791    
2       0.276 0.783           60380 0.674    
3      -0.481 0.633           28392 0.116    
4       2.68  0.008 * *       94507 0.195    
5       1.95  0.054           56902 0.349
```

Here is the code for my data:

```
structure(list(statistic.x = c(0.533, 0.276, -0.481, 2.678, 1.95, 
1.996), p.value.x = c("0.595", "0.783", "0.633", "0.008 * *", 
"0.054", "0.051"), statistic.y = c(115806, 60380, 28392, 94507, 
56902, 37688), p.value.y = c("0.791", "0.674", "0.116", "0.195", 
"0.349", "0.397")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Your assumption *it isn't possible that two colums have the same names in R* is wrong

Comment: Yes. You're right! It is possible

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have any problem setting names using `colnames`

```
> colnames(dat) <- c( "statistic", "p.value", "statistic", "p.value" )
> dat
  statistic   p.value statistic p.value
1     0.533     0.595    115806   0.791
2     0.276     0.783     60380   0.674
3    -0.481     0.633     28392   0.116
4     2.678 0.008 * *     94507   0.195
5     1.950     0.054     56902   0.349
6     1.996     0.051     37688   0.397
```